# should people with expunged convictions be up front about it?

Tags: united-states, background-check, new-hires

So I have a friend that took a deferred adjudication plea for a misdemeanor theft charge. The problem is that that's now showing up when employers do background checks on this friend and they're being turned down for jobs because of that.

They're considering getting a lawyer to get the charge expunged but I don't know how much that'd help with background checks. Would it still show up, albeit with a status of "expunged"? And if so would being up front about it help?

In lieu of expunction would being up front about it still be advisable?

And in either case if being up front were advisable, what would be a good thing to say?

Comment: I think by definition expunged is removed although I don't have any way to back that up.  I would advise not freely volunteering the information but answering honestly if questioned.

Comment: That's four questions of which the first one is off-topic here (and the 2nd and 3rd are identical). Can you [edit] your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "expunged" conviction means that your friend's conviction is off the official records as far as the general public is concerned including your friend's prospective employers, and he has the right to say the he does not have that conviction. If all of your friend's convictions are expunged, then your friend has the right to say in their applications that they haven't been convicted of any criminal offense.

Now, whoever runs the background check may encounter outdated records that show the original conviction, but your friend may respond by stating that these records are outdated and that his conviction has been expunged.  Your friend's response, including documentation to that effect, should take care of the result of the background check so far as the prospective employer is concerned.

Comment: Great answer. Just a comment to say that even when a record is expunged, it may not show up on many background checks such as when applying for rental housing. However, expunged records will show up in the federal NICS system when ran through the FBI and DOJ. Some people with expunged records have ran into issues with obtaining security clearances in for government and financial sector jobs. Officially, only a Presidential pardon can wipe out all traces of a criminal accusation.

Comment: Altho the fact that you received a presidential pardon would probably be documented online and given that it seems like employers could still discriminate against you based on that..

Comment: And unofficially, there could be court records obtained before expunction, news accounts, people's memories... nobody, not even the President, can promise to wipe those out.  (Maybe the Ministry of Truth could handle it.)

Answer (score 4):

You friend should consult a lawyer, because it seems to be dependent on your jurisdiction. Wikipedia says:

> Each jurisdiction whose law allows expungement has its own definitions of expungement proceedings. Generally, expungement is the process to "remove from general review" the records pertaining to a case. In many jurisdictions, however, the records may not completely "disappear" and may still be available to law enforcement, to sentencing judges on subsequent offenses, and to corrections facilities to which the individual may be sentenced on subsequent convictions.

Your friend should act accordingly. If there are still signs of it to be found in a background check *and your friend is asked about it up front*, then by all means answer honestly.

Personally, I cannot see any good coming from mentioning it proactively. If they don't ask, then they don't want to hear about it.